# load data from sql server table and populate textboxes using dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

i pass selected ProductID as a string to retrieve data from row with the same ProductID

```
private void modifyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (productsTable.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedrowindex = productsTable.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = productsTable.Rows[selectedrowindex];
            string ProductID = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["ProductID"].Value);
            
            ProductModel product = db.LoadProduct(ProductID);
        }
    }
```

then i try to load data and get it as a ProductModel to populate textboxes with it

```
public ProductModel LoadProduct(string productId)
    {
        ProductModel output;

        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(CnnString(db)))
        {
            output = connection.Query
                (@"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", new { ProductID = productId }).Single();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

i get error
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: "Cannot implicitly convert type object to SalesManager.Models.ProductModel

i tried before with a List and it seem to work, but then i dont know to to get objects and convert the to strings.

Comment: You are using Entity.  You have to read/write to the c# classes in the db classes.  Entity already has a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the generic overload of Query, eg

```
output = connection.Query<ProductModel>(@"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", new { ProductID = productId }).Single();
```